# android HttpHostConnectException while trying to connect to a gwt page

Tags: java, android, servlets, gwt

i wrote a gwt project that works already. the only problem i have is, that i can not connect to the server with my self programmed android app. i can start my gwt page at http://127.0.0.1:8888 with the browser, but when i try to connect to a servlet that maps to http://127.0.0.1:8888/ip/ i get a HttpHostConnectException  connection refused exception. i can access http://127.0.0.1:8888/ip/ easily with the browser easily but not with my android app. here is the android code where i try to connect to the server

```
try{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1:8888/ip/");
    ...
    execute = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e); // connection refused
}
```

the doPost() method of that servlet (mapped to /ip/) never gets called when i try to post to it with my android app.

the same structure worked with my vaadin and jquery projects perfectly. just gwt is creating this problem.

Comment: with "the browser", you are talking about the browser in the android phone?

Comment: no, a browser like chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem existed only locally (most probably because of the super develop mode). after i replaced the ip in the bindaddress in the intellij idea debug configuration from 127.0.0.1 to the device ip, the problem was solved